# How do I update my StreetPass profile?

Tags: bravely-default

How do I update my character's StreetPass profile in *Bravely Default*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, this can only be done in battle with a few conditions.

Choose `Summon` in the menu and then choose `Send`. Then choose a single action. The character must complete the command that turn (it looks like `Jump` won't work). At the end of the battle it will say "Updating StreetPass data". Then when you check the StreetPass screen you can see the updated character and action there.

Comment: If you want to change the message that your Mii sends out when StreetPassing: Choose "Tactics" from the menu, then "Friends". On the bottom screen, tap "Edit" and enter a new message.